# Does git commit --amend overwrite the old commit completly?

Tags: git

To a local repository I accidentally committed a file whit a password in it that should not go out to the public (it was there for a lazy testing purpose...).

I saved the file again whit out the password and used `git commit --amend` to commit the file again.
Is the password now gone for good or can it still be found some where in the repository?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you haven't performed a `git push` to a remote repository before doing amending, then the commit is not available in that remote repository. It will not be pushed in the future, either.

However, your *local* repository still contains the old commit which you can see by running `git reflog`.

The actual (old) commit can then be shown with a command like:

```
git show HEAD@{1}
```

(assuming that you committed something and then amended it without further commits / branch switching)

To get rid of that commit locally, you should have a look at `git gc`. When you run it as-is, it will remove older, dangling commits with a certain age.

Comment: Thanks. Knowing it doesn't leaf my local repository is the main thing. But when I try to remove it local whit "git gc --aggressive --prune=2013-04-22" it didn't remove it. I also tried it after I used "git reflog delete abcdef" to remove it from the reflog. But "git show abcdef" still shows the password. Any suggestion to continue?

Comment: `git reflog expire --all --expire-unreachable=0 && git gc --aggressive --prune=now` works for me. Credits to http://www.ducea.com/2012/02/07/howto-completely-remove-a-file-from-git-history/